# Simple existence and uniqueness proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across the following exercise:

"Prove that there is a unique real number $x$ such that for every real number $y$, $xy+x-4 = 4y$".

In other words: $\exists!x\in \mathbb{R} \forall \mathbb{R} (xy + x - 4 = 4y)$.

At a first glance it is clear that 4 is the right number, but I wanted to write a textbook solution using this schema:

$\exists x (P(x) \land \forall y (P(y) \rightarrow y=x)$

I started with solving for $x$:

$xy + x - 4 = 4y$

$\Rightarrow xy + x = 4y + 4$

$\Rightarrow x(y + 1) = 4y + 4$

$\Rightarrow x = \frac{4y+4}{y+1} = \frac{4(y+1)}{(y+1)} = 4$

Here the trouble begins: According to this solution

https://www.inchmeal.io/htpi/ch-3/sec-3.6.html (scroll down to solution number 2) we have to do a proof by cases. I don't buy that. I think the reasoning behind the linked solution is that the above calculation is only allowed if $y\neq-1$. To me that seems wrong, because one can always expand a fraction with 1, so we are not really dividing by zero.

Proof of existence:

Let $x=4$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Substituting $x=4$ in the above equation yields $4y+4-4=4y$, which is correct.

I think this concludes the existence proof. However, the uniqueness proof causes me problems.

Proof of uniqueness:

Let $z \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary such that $zy + z - 4 = 4y$. Thus,

$zy + z - 4 = 4y = xy + x -4$

$\Rightarrow zy + z = xy + x$

$\Rightarrow z(y+1) = x(y+1)$

$\Rightarrow z = x$

I initially thought that this is it. However, the division in the last step is only allowed if $y \neq -1$. But then my justification for my calculation and my rejection of proof by cases does not seem right or the phrasing of the exercise is not correct, which I seriously doubt.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: In the question statement, it should be $4y$ on the RHS, not $x-y$

Comment: This makes no sense. Set $y=0$, This gives $x=4$, but with $y=1$ we get $x=-3$.

Comment: What do you mean by - "expand a fraction with 1"?

Comment: @Ishan Deo Thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: @Ishan Deo I am not a native speaker, so I used a translation of the German phrase "Bruch erweitern".

Comment: Do you mean by any chance the identity - $\frac{1}{1-r} = \sum_0^\infty r^i$?

Comment: @Ishan No. The whole thing is verbatim from "How to Prove It" by Daniel Velleman and I am sure no summation sign has so far appeared in the book up to that exercise.

Comment: Could you share the passage?

Comment: The exercise is from "How to Prove It" by Daniel Velleman, 2nd edition, section 3.6, Page 153, exercise number 2.

Comment: @copper.hat If we set $y=1$, we still get $x=4$

Comment: @Maximilian: The question was edited after my remark.

Answer (score 1):

$xy+x-4 = 4y$ **iff** $(y+1)(x-4) = 0$

If $x=4$ then the equation is true for all $y$.

If the equation is true for all $y$, then it is true for $y=0$, and hence $x=4$.

Comment: Thanks for engaging. Could you however be more specific to the problems I have raised?

Comment: I was. If the equation is true for all $y$, it is true or $y=0$. Setting $y=0$ implies $x=4$. Hence $x$ is unique.

Comment: The queston is: Where is the mistake in my reasoning: You are simply giving a solution. I want a full-fledged explanation of the reasoning and why mine is right/wrong.

Comment: Well, petulance is not a great incentive. For uniqueness, you can pick any $y$ you want to demonstrate. In particular, you can select any $y \ne -1$

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really explain your mistake.

It seems simpler to prove uniqueness indirectly, by showing that 
(1) 4 satisfies the condition

and that

(2) any number different from 4 does not satisfy.

I've tried to do that in the following derivation.

[image]